# Nuxt3 + Firebase Auth NodeJS SDK: Using Nuxt API routes and setting custom user claims -- Error: "cannot find any route matching..."

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, nuxtjs3

I am trying to set custom claims to a user record. I am using Nuxt3's server api like so:

`pages/test.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="setCustomClaim()">Update custom claim</button>
    <pre>{{ user }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user'

const user = ref(null)

const setCustomClaim = async () => {
  const userStore = useUserStore()
  const response = await $fetch(
    `/api/users/updateCustomClaims/${userStore.user.email}`
  )
  user.value = response
}
</script>
```

**The above and below code WORKS:**
The custom claim is successfully updated.
`/server/api/users/updateCustomClaims/[email].js`:

```js
import { auth } from '@/server/utils/firebase'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
    const user = await auth.getUserByEmail(event.context.params.email)
      const response = await auth.setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { admin: true })
      return response
  } catch (error) {
    return console.log('Error in updating custom claims', error)
  }
```

**But....why this does not work? See error message below:** I wanted to check user's email verification before proceeding with custom claim update...

```js
import { auth } from '@/server/utils/firebase'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
    const user = await auth.getUserByEmail(event.context.params.email)
    if (user.emailVerified) {
      const response = await auth.setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { admin: true })
      return response
    } else {
      return 'User email not verified'
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return console.log('Error in updating custom claims', error)
  }
```

Trying to check that the user's email is verified causes server error message:

```
{
    "url": "/api/users/updateCustomClaims/<removed>@gmail.com",
    "statusCode": 404,
    "statusMessage": "Cannot find any route matching /api/users/updateCustomClaims/<removed>@gmail.com.",
    "message": "Cannot find any route matching /api/users/updateCustomClaims/<removed>@gmail.com.",
    "stack": ""
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did not see it. I dont' think it's related to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. In my case, I was incorrectly returning data. I need to make sure the return is JSON encoded:

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
    const user = await auth.getUserByEmail(event.context.params.email)
    if (user.emailVerified) {
      const response = await auth.setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { admin: true })
      return {
        status: 200,
        statusMessage: 'OK'
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error in updating custom claims', error)
    return {
      status: 500,
      statusMessage: 'Error in updating custom claims'
    }
  }
})
```